# Is it possible to do a loop inside the option page of plugins on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming

I've encounter this issue during the develop of my plugin. 
I've to loop through all the pages of the website and print the titles and the IDs of them.
When I do the simply loop it just don't print anything.

Is there a way for do a loop inside options of my plugin?

Comment: Could you please post more details, like the code you have tried so far and all?

Comment: did you tried this 

    <?php
     $pages = get_pages(); 
       foreach ($pages as $page) {
        $page_title = $page->post_title;
        $page_id = $page->ID;
       }
    ?>

Comment: @Ashkar yep, i tried that code. It works but don't do what i've to do. This only works for pages. I need something for every custom post type. This is the simple loop i've tried <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
     the_title();
     endwhile;
     endif; ?>

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

I don't know if there's some kind of block inside the plugin options page but we can loop through every custom post type with a little portion of code:

```
<?php 

    //Search only for custom post type which is public.
    $args = array('public'=>true);

    //Get all custom post type name
    $allMyCustomPostTypes = get_post_types($args); 

    foreach ($allMyCustomPostTypes as $myCustomPostType) {

        //Create a filter for get_posts with every custom post type
        $filter = array('numberposts' => 5, 'post_type' => $myCustomPostType);

        //Pass the value to *get_posts*
        $theposts = get_posts($filter);

        foreach ($theposts as $thepost) {

            //Easy print the name of the current post of the current custom post type
            echo $thepost->post_title;

        };

    }; 

?>
```

Here we are, hope this helps somebody.